# perl で while(<STDIN>) は何を意味しますか？

Tags: perl

perl初心者です。
perlファイルで `while(<STDIN>)`って何かまったくわかりません。
何ですかね？

Answer (score 3):

`STDIN` はファイルハンドルで、標準入力にアサインされています。
標準入力とは
キーボードからの入力やパイプ（例：`cat sample.txt || perl test.pl`） や
リダイレクト（例：`perl test.pl < sample.txt`）されたファイルのことです。

`<STDIN>` は、
`<ファイルハンドル>`で、指定されたファイルから一行を読込み、変数`$_`に暗黙に代入されます。
つまり、標準入力から一行読み込んで`$_`に内容を設定します。

`while(<STDIN>)` は、
`while(条件)` で条件が失敗するまで繰り返します。
この場合標準入力が最後（キーボードの場合は`EOF` が(windowsの場合は<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, UNIX系の場合は<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>で）入力される）になるまで繰り返し入力します。

ちなみに
`while(<STDIN>)` は、`STDIN`を省略して`while(<>)` と書くことができます。(※コマンドライン引数に入力ファイル（複数可）が与えられなかった場合)

Comment: perl はもう何年も使っていないので間違ってたらすみません。
`while (<STDIN>)` は見た目の通り標準入力だけですが、
`while (<>)` は、コマンドライン引数に与えたファイルを全て開いて入力としていませんでしたか?

Comment: @masm ご指摘の通りです。 `while(<>)`が標準入力の読み込みになるのは、コマンドライン引数としてファイルが与えられていない場合です。誤解を与える書き方でした。注記を追加しました。ご指摘ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちょっと蛇足気味の補足: この場合は暗黙の `defined` が追加されるので、`while(defined($_ = <STDIN>)) { ... }` と見なされますね。(最終行が "0" のみで改行が無い場合対策でこのような仕様になっています。) cf. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators

Comment: @yasu 補註ありがとうございます。